# is it an equivalent definition of the Schwartz Space? all real smooth function that $ f^{(k)}(\infty)=0=f^{(k)}(-\infty)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators, schwartz-space

## Background:

1. I have only taken half semester Analysis course
2. It's in a german script from a **linear algebra** course on **scalar products** and **self-adjoint endomorphisms**, and so on. It mentions such a vector space $S(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}$:

## Notation:

Let $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be all infinitely differentiable real functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

## Definition of $S(\mathbb{R})$ and contents in the script:

$ S(\mathbb{R}):= \{ f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) ~|~ \exists  \text{ a finite interval $ I_f \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$  and all derivatives of $f$  outside $I_f$ are $0$ } \}  (\star)$

The script also provides such notation: $  f^{(k)}(\infty)=0=f^{(k)}(-\infty) $

The script then claims that

(1) We can define a scalar product as follows:

$\langle f,g\rangle := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)g(t)dt~~ (f,g \in S(\mathbb{R})) $

(2)The second derivative (Laplace Operator)$\Delta:S(\mathbb{R}) \to S(\mathbb{R});~ f \mapsto f'' $ is self-adjoint

...

## Question

1. I am wondering if this particular vector space $S(R)$ had a ***name*** and why letter $S$ is used here.

ChatGPT suggested the **Schwartz Space**.

But all the definition and alternation definitions for schwartz spaces' that I found look very different to definition $\star$, they usually involves usage of a Supermum (Supermum Norm?)and include notations that I am not familiar with.

for example

[Equivalent definitions of Schwartz Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708452/equivalent-definitions-of-schwartz-space)

[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/ch5A.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m218a_09/ch5A.pdf)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space

And sometimes $S(\mathbb{R}^{n}), C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n})$,not $S(\mathbb{R}), C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, is used for schwartz space.

**So is this $S(\mathbb{R})$ schwartz space or not??** If not, what is it? If it is, is there any material for schwartz space that contains this definition $\star$ ?

2. Is $S(\mathbb{R})$ an infinite-dimensional vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shwartz is a space of *rapidly* decreasing functions.

Your space is a space of decreasing functions. So no it is not. It nowhere says how fast it decreases.

Long sentences: your space is a space of smooth functions whose derivatives (including the function itself) decay at infinity. Shwartz is a space of smooth functions whose derivatives (including the function itself) decay at infinity *faster than any power*.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! one more question: if a schwartz space always 'decays at infinity' as well, does it mean that Schwartz Space is a vector *sub*space of this S(R)?

Comment: @IAN16 Yes, it is a subspace.